# Use PrimerCSS.io in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am building an app with Laravel & I want to build it with [PrimerCSS.io](http://primercss.io.) and remove Bootstrap completely.

I followed the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/primer-css#install), but I could not complete it.
I replaced `@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

with
`@import "primer-css/index.scss";` 
in
`resources/assets/sass/app.scss` and ran `npm run watch`.

But encountered problem

> Module build failed: 
>   @import "primer-css/index.scss;
>   File to import not found or unreadable:

Comment: Try making that path relative to the file that you're importing it in. Something like: `@import '../../../node_modules/primer-css/index.scss';` (if you're in `/resources/assets/css`).

Comment: Did not help though. Same error `Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
@import '../../../node_modules/primer-css/index.scss';
`

Comment: The path I used is an example. You need to change it to the relative path of the primer-css.index file.

Comment: Any solution? I tried several matches but failed. My  `node_modules` directory is at project root (`/xampp/htdocs/project/`), `app.scss` is located at `xampp/htdocs/project/resources/assets/sass/app.scss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I got to work with a fresh install of Laravel 5.5 ([this Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/how-to-configure-includepaths-for-sass-on-mix?page=1) led me on the right track).

First, we need to use the [includePaths option](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#includepaths) for node-sass:

```
// webpack.mix.js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
        includePaths: ["node_modules"]
   });
```

Then, we can just include the primer-css index.scss file:

```
// resources/assets/sass/app.scss
@import "~primer-css/index";
```

*(Note that the above `~` is equivalent to `../../../node_modules/`)*

Comment: Yes that worked. But how can I produce multiple files? Like `app.scss` to `public/css` & `main.scss` to `public/css ` while both referencing `includePaths: ["node_modules"]`?